# Zabbix Comparing Hashes of 4 different hosts

Tags: triggers, zabbix

I currently have 4 web nodes that should all have the same contents. But i would like to create a trigger when any of the 4 contents changes. I currently monitor the hashes of the folders that the contents are in, this returns a hash value that i would like to compare using a trigger.
However the most recent solution that i've been able to find was from 2017, and i was wondering if there was a better way of doing this.
Also would i be able to do this using a discovery (LLD) trigger prototype?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monitoring the hash is a good way to ensure content is consistent. You can manually create a trigger confronting the items, but i don't think you can use a LLD.

The LLD can find all the needed items, but cannot create a trigger with multiple items in the way you need it.

The trigger would be something like

```
{host1:hash.last()} <> {host2:hash.last()} or {host2:hash.last()} <> {host3:hash.last()}
```

and with n hosts, you'll need n-1 conditions. I'm afraid that with many hosts, your best option is building a script to create the trigger, through API.

Comment: Custom scripting was the option i found. Thank you for your answer